# Как вывести данные из Datatable Flet

Tags: python, flet

Может кто знает и подскажет как в Flet получить все данные из DataTable?

```
   self.table = DataTable(
        bgcolor="white",
        border_radius=5,
        column_spacing=5,

        heading_row_color='#FAEBD7',
        # data_row_color='red',
        columns=[
            DataColumn(
                Text("Заголовок1"),
                on_sort=lambda e: print(f"{e.column_index}, {e.ascending}"),
            ),
            DataColumn(
                Text("Заголовок 2"),
                on_sort=lambda e: print(f"{e.column_index}, {e.ascending}"),
            ),
           
        ],
        rows=[]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно обратиться к элементу `DataTable` и взять значение атрибута `columns`, в который ты должен передать элемент `DataColumn`, и `rows`, в который ты должен передать элемент `DataRow`.

А `DataColumn` имеет атрибут `label`, в который ты передаёшь другой элемент.

А значение передаваемого элемента - в его атрибуте (этот атрибут, у каждого элемента по-разному). В твоём случае `value` (Потому что ты передал в `label` элемент `Text`).

А `DataRow` имеет атрибут `cells`, в который есть атрибут `DataCell`, который имеет атрибут `content`. В который ты передаёшь другой элемент, в большинстве случае это `Text`.

А значение передаваемого элемента в его атрибуте (`value`, если `Text`).

В принципе, ничего сложного, просто надо читать документацию.

Если в таблице нет ничего кроме текста (без иконок, фото, кнопок и т.д. и т.п.), то код будет примерно таким:

```
#Получить столбцы таблицы
for i in table.columns:
    print(i.label.value)

#Получить строки таблицы
for rows in table.rows:
    for cells in rows.cells:
        print(cells.content.value)
```